# Odata exception while retrieving keywords

Tags: 2011, odata

When performing odata operation to retrieve all the keywords by using following syntax:

```
var keywords = service.Keywords.ToList();
```

I am getting following exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled   HResult=-2146233079
>   Message=A navigation link 'Parent' was found with type 'feed', but its
>   matching navigation property is of kind EntityReference. A navigation
>   link with type 'feed' must match a navigation property of kind
>   EntitySetReference.   Source=Microsoft.Data.Services.Client
>   StackTrace:
>          at System.Data.Services.Client.Materialization.ODataReaderEntityMaterializer.ODataFeedOrEntryReader.TryRead()
>          at System.Data.Services.Client.Materialization.ODataReaderEntityMaterializer.ODataFeedOrEntryReader.ReadEntryCore()
>          at System.Data.Services.Client.Materialization.ODataReaderEntityMaterializer.ODataFeedOrEntryReader.TryReadEntry(MaterializerEntry&
>   entry)
>          at System.Data.Services.Client.Materialization.ODataReaderEntityMaterializer.ODataFeedOrEntryReader.d__0.MoveNext()
>          at System.Data.Services.Client.Materialization.ODataReaderEntityMaterializer.ODataFeedOrEntryReader.Read()
>          at System.Data.Services.Client.Materialization.ODataReaderEntityMaterializer.ReadNextFeedOrEntry()
>          at System.Data.Services.Client.Materialization.ODataEntityMaterializer.ReadImplementation()
>          at System.Data.Services.Client.MaterializeAtom.MoveNextInternal()
>          at System.Data.Services.Client.MaterializeAtom.MoveNext()
>          at System.Linq.Enumerable.d__b1`1.MoveNext()
>          at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>          at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>          at TestNavigationFetch.Program.GetTaxonomy() in c:\Program.cs:line
>   25
>          at TestNavigationFetch.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Program.cs:line
>   14
>          at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
>          at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()   InnerException: Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataException
>          HResult=-2146233079
>          Message=A navigation link 'Parent' was found with type 'feed', but its matching navigation property is of kind EntityReference. A
>   navigation link with type 'feed' must match a navigation property of
>   kind EntitySetReference.
>          Source=Microsoft.Data.OData
>          StackTrace:
>               at Microsoft.Data.OData.Atom.ODataAtomReader.StartNavigationLink(ODataAtomReaderNavigationLinkDescriptor
>   navigationLinkDescriptor)
>               at Microsoft.Data.OData.Atom.ODataAtomReader.ReadAtNavigationLinkEndImplementation()
>               at Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataReaderCore.ReadImplementation()
>               at Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataReaderCore.ReadSynchronously()
>               at Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataReaderCore.InterceptException[T](Func`1
>   action)
>               at Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataReaderCore.Read()
>               at System.Data.Services.Client.Materialization.ODataReaderEntityMaterializer.ODataFeedOrEntryReader.TryRead()
>          InnerException:

Please suggest what am I missing?

Comment: Is this 2011 (6.0) or 2011 SP1 (6.1)? There were quite some fixes around OData for SP1 (and possibly a few more in the Hotfix Rollup 1 and 2). Please add details of the version.

Comment: 2011 Sp1 with HR2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checked with Tridion support and found out that this was a bug with 2011 and it was fixed in 2013.